# How Lucene.net filter works

Tags: c#, lucene.net

i got a piece of code to add filter with Lucene.net but good explanation was not there to understand the code. so here i paste the code for explanation.

```
List<SearchResults> Searchresults = new List<SearchResults>();

        string indexFileLocation = @"C:\o";
        Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir =     Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexFileLocation);

        string[] searchfields = new string[] { "fname", "lname", "dob", "id"};
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);

        Filter fil= new QueryWrapperFilter(new TermQuery( new Term(field, "5/12/1998")));
        var hits = indexSearcher.Search(QueryMaker(searchString, searchfields), fil);

        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
        {
            SearchResults result = new SearchResults();
            result.fname = hits.Doc(i).GetField("fname").StringValue();
            result.lname = hits.Doc(i).GetField("lname").StringValue();
            result.dob = hits.Doc(i).GetField("dob").StringValue();
            result.id = hits.Doc(i).GetField("id").StringValue();
            Searchresults.Add(result);

        }
```

i need explanation for the below two line

```
    Filter fil= new QueryWrapperFilter(new TermQuery( new Term(field, "5/12/1998")));
    var hits = indexSearcher.Search(QueryMaker(searchString, searchfields), fil);
```

i just like to know first lucene search & pull all data and after implement filter or from the beginning lucene pull data based on filter? please guide. thanks.

Comment: Lucene indexes everything at first run, so that line is filtering from the data file that was created so, it is not so much bringing all the data back as it is already there, it is filtering the already indexed information using the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i just like to know first lucene search & pull all data and after implement filter or from the beginning lucene pull data based on filter? please guide. thanks.

Lucene.Net will perform your search AND your filtered query and after it, it will "merge" the result. The reason to do it I believe is to cache the filtered query, because it will be more likely to have a hit on the next time than the search query.

Comment: r u trying to say lucene first fetch data and after fetching result then it apply filter on fetch result set? am i right or wrong ? if possible explain with example as a result i can visualize what u try to say. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, lucene will fetch the documents id with the search you are doing (name=test) and after it, it will fetch the documents id with the date (e.g.) 5/12/1998 and after it, it will go over all the result set and collect those who have both date = 5/12/1998 as name=test.

Comment: Any example with grouping query with filter? Couldn't find much on lucene.net. Really very confusing. Official document is not even seems very rich